# TypeError al intentar iniciar sesión en una API con seguridad JWT y cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, axios, spring-security

Estoy construyendo una API con Spring y seguridad JWT la cual sirve como intermediaria entre una base de datos mysql y el cliente, en este caso será una pequeña aplicación web react.

Cuando pruebo mi endpoint desde postman la respuesta que recibo correctamente es:

[image: respuesta postman a /api/auth/signin]

Como verán pareciera que todo funciona correctamente:
[image: postman cookies]

Al intentar iniciar sesión desde mi aplicación de React, recibo un error de

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').

Estoy utilizando el paquete axios para realizar la solicitud POST al endpoint de inicio de sesión. La respuesta incluye las cookies en la cabecera de la respuesta. Intenté extraer las cookies usando `response.headers['set-cookie']`, pero parece que obtengo el error de TypeError:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () =>
    {
        const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

        const handleLogin = async ( e ) =>
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                try {
                    const response = await axios.post(
                        'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin',
                        {
                            username: username,
                            password: password,
                        }
                    );
                    console.log(response);
                    
                    // Obtener las cookies de la respuesta
                    const cookies = response.headers[ 'Set-Cookie' ];
                    // Parsear las cookies para extraer solo el valor del token
                    const token = cookies[ 0 ].split(';')[ 0 ].split('=')[ 1 ];


                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);


                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error de inicio de sesión: ', error);
                }
            };

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Iniciar sesión</h2>
                <form onSubmit={ handleLogin }>
                    <div>
                        <label>Nombre de usuario:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={ username }
                            onChange={ ( e ) => setUsername(e.target.value) }
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Contraseña:</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            value={ password }
                            onChange={ ( e ) => setPassword(e.target.value) }
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    };

export default Login;
```

A continuación, intentaré explicar mi API la cual desarrollé siguiendo las practicas explicadas en:
[bezkoder](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-login-example-mysql/)

Mi API es un backend desarrollado con Spring que proporciona servicios de autenticación y autorización utilizando JsonWebTokens(JWT) y cookies.
El objetivo principal es permitir que los usuarios inicien sesión de forma segura y puedan acceder a los recursos protegidos dentro de la aplicación.

El flujo de autenticación comienza cuando un usuario envía una solicitud POST al endpoint */api/auth/signin* con su nombre de usuario y contraseña.

Endpoint "/api/auth/signin" de clase AuthController:

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);

        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
                .body(new UserInfoResponse(
                        userDetails.getId(),
                        userDetails.getUsername(),
                        userDetails.getEmail(),
                        roles)
                );
    }
```

El controlador correspondiente, *AuthController*, utiliza el *AuthenticationManager* de Spring Security para autenticar las credenciales del usuario. Si las credenciales son válidas, se genera un objeto *Authentication* y se establece en el contexto de seguridad utilizando *SecurityContextHolder*.

Clase de configuración de Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/api/test/**", "/api/formularios/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Luego, se crea un token JWT utilizando la biblioteca *JwtUtils*. Este token contiene información sobre el usuario autenticado, como su ID, nombre de usuario, correo electrónico y roles. El token JWT se agrega como una cookie de respuesta y se envía al cliente en la respuesta HTTP.

*JwtUtils*: es una utilidad para trabajar con tokens JWT. Proporciona métodos para generar un token JWT, obtener el nombre de usuario de un token, validar la autenticidad del token y manejar las cookies relacionadas con el token JWT. La clase utiliza una clave secreta y algoritmo HS512 para firmar y verificar los tokens.

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${metabolom.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${metabolom.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    @Value("${metabolom.app.jwtCookieName}")
    private String jwtCookieName;

    public String getJwtFromCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, jwtCookieName);
        if (cookie != null) {
            return cookie.getValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ResponseCookie generateJwtCookie(UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal) {
        String jwt = generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
        System.out.println(jwt);
        return ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookieName, jwt).path("/api").maxAge(24 * 60 * 60).httpOnly(true).build();
    }

    public ResponseCookie getCleanJwtCookie() {
        return ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookieName, null).path("/api").build();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Generar una clave segura para el algoritmo HS512
    Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }
}
```

*AuthTokenFilter*: extiende `OncePerRequestFilter` de Spring Security y se utiliza para filtrar las solicitudes entrantes. Comprueba si se proporciona un token JWT válido en la solicitud. Si el token es válido, se autentica al usuario y se establece su contexto de seguridad. La clase utiliza `JwtUtils` para validar y obtener el nombre de usuario a partir del token JWT.

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt == null) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            if (jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {

                System.out.println("jwtuser-> " + jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt));
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities()
                        );
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token");
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication error");
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jwt = jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request);
        return jwt;
    }
}
```

y *AuthEntryPoint*: implementa la interfaz `AuthenticationEntryPoint` de Spring Security. Actúa como un punto de entrada para la autenticación y maneja las respuestas no autorizadas. Cuando se produce un error de autenticación, como un token JWT inválido, esta clase captura la excepción y devuelve una respuesta de error JSON al cliente.

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
}
```

En el lado del cliente, estoy utilizando React para construir la interfaz de usuario como la definí al principio del post. Al enviar la solicitud POST al endpoint */api/auth/signin*, obtengo la respuesta del servidor y un `console.log(response)` a través de handleLogin.
`Console.log(response)`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "tobias_zoppi@hotmail.com",
        "roles": [
            "ROLE_ADMIN"
        ]
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "expires": "0",
        "pragma": "no-cache"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin",
        "data": "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"123a\"}"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Realmente no sé en qué me estoy equivocando.